# Why this code says echo is off?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

What is wrong with this code? It says `ECHO is off`.

```
@ECHO off
set /p pattern=Enter id:
findstr %pattern% .\a.txt > result
if %errorlevel%==0 (
set var2= <result
echo %var2%
set var1=%var2:~5,3%
echo %var1% > test.txt
echo %var1%
) else (
echo error
)
del result
pause
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try removing `@ECHO off` on top?

Comment: Then it says Echo is on.

Comment: For reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170802-00/?p=96735

Answer (score 73):

If your variable is empty somewhere, it will be the same as having the command "echo" on its own, which will just print the status of echo.

To avoid this, you should replace all your `echo` commands with something like this:

```
echo var2: %var2%
```

That way, if `%var2%` is empty it will just print "echo var2:" instead of "echo off".

Comment: Ok, but I expect var2 to be not empty, have you run it?

Comment: Then it's not an issue with `echo`, it's an issue with the code or files you are trying to read. To debug it though, it would be better to prefix each echo as mentioned in my answer. At least you will know where your problem is.

Comment: although 'result' has some string value, var2= <result seems not working? Any suggestion?

Comment: Great answer regarding "variable empty somewhere = status of echo"... thanks!

Answer (score 31):

As Laurent stated, it's not a problem of the `ECHO`, it's a problem of your code.

In batch files, blocks are completely parsed before they are executed.
While parsing, all percent expansion will be done, so it seems that your variables can't be changed inside a block.

But for this exists the delayed expansion, the delayed expansion will be evaluated in the moment of execution not while parsing the block.

It must be enabled, as per default the delayed expansion is disabled.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p pattern=Enter id:
findstr %pattern% .\a.txt > result
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  set var2= <result
  echo(!var2!
  set var1=!var2:~5,3!
  echo(!var1! > test.txt
  echo(!var1!
) else (
  echo error
)
del result
```

I used here the construct `echo(` instead of `echo` as this will ensure echoing an empty line even if the variable is empty.

Comment: this is the first example I have seen that solved my problem, I need to change the percent signs to exclamations... the docs don't appear to be very explicit about that

Answer (score 15):

Not sure, if this post is still read, but nevertheless.
You should try the following:
On top of the code right after `@echo off` you have to put in

```
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Additionally anywhere you want to use variables changed in a block of brackets (like `For-Loops` or `If's`) you have to change the `%`into `!` to get
`!varname!`

Answer (score 0):

[image]First create a file a.txt in the same directory u have this batch file ... write some text in that...Note: only Windows 2000
Windows ME
Windows XP
Windows Vista
Windows 7 supports FINDSTR

```
set /p pattern=Enter id:
findstr %pattern% a.txt > __query.tmp
set /p result=<__query.tmp
if %errorlevel%==0 (
set var2= %result%
echo %var2%
set var1= %var2:~5,3%
echo %var1% > test.txt
echo %var1%
) else (
echo error
)
del __query.tmp
pause
```

run this bath file .. you will find a substring(start=5,length=3) of the first line of string you have in a.txt in a newly created file test.txt. Finally got it working !

Comment: what are you typing in Enter id:

Comment: by the way 'set var1= %var2%:~5,3' should be 'set var1= %var2:~5,3%'

Comment: are you not getting any different result other than echo on or off ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem is to put the "echo"s after the if block is completed. 
Try this:

```
@ECHO off
set /p pattern=Enter id:
findstr %pattern% .\a.txt > result
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    set var2= <result
    set var1=%var2:~5,3%
    goto print 
) else (
    echo error
    goto result
)
:print
echo %var2%
echo %var1% > test.txt
echo %var1%

:result
del result
pause
```

This way you can see the solution as you wanted. 
Cheers!  ;]