# How do i make cmd prompt not show "echo is off" when i type @echo off

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a problem. I'm coding a batch file in Notepad, and when I type "@echo off" (without the quotes) it turns off echo but also displays "ECHO is off" (again, without the quotes) in the CMD Prompt window. Please help me!!

Comment: How this youtube channel can help us answering this question ?

Comment: It would help to share your actual code, although it could be a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334850/why-this-code-says-echo-is-off

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing

```
"@echo off>nul"  (without quotes)
```

Which might stop it from displaying anything.